# Get the most recent records across multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection of "purchases", how can I get each person's **most recent** purchase?

Each person is unique on `first_name` and `last_name`.

**Example Collection:**

```
[
  {
    first_name: "Don",
    last_name: "Foobar",
    date: 11111111, // The unix timestamp of purchase
    purchase: {...}
  },
  {
    first_name: "Don",
    last_name: "Foobar",
    date: 22222222,
    purchase: {...}
  },
  {
    first_name: "James",
    last_name: "McManason",
    date: 12341234,
    purchase: {...}
  }
  ...
]
```

**What I've tried:**

This below code would work (super sub-optimally) given a collection of the people's names to iterate through:

```
collection
  .find({ first_name: "Tom", last_name: "Brady" })
  .sort({ date: -1 })
  .limit(1)

collection
  .find({ first_name: "James", last_name: "Foo" })
  .sort({ date: -1 })
  .limit(1)

collection
  .find({ first_name: "Marcia", last_name: "Bar" })
  .sort({ date: -1 })
  .limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need a more generic solution? If so then try this out:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $sort: { date: -1}}, // sort by date descending
{
  $group: {
    _id: { firstName: "$first_name", lastName: "$last_name"}, // group by
                                                             // first and last name
    purchase: {$first: "$purchase"} // get the first purchase since the documents are 
                                    // ordered by date and the first is also the latest
  }
}
])
```

sorting through your complete collection though is not so efficient so you should consider adding a `$match` before the `$sort`.